# Cannot connect to OpenShift mysql remotely with jdbc

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc, openshift

I am trying to connect to a remote database on openshift using jdbc.
Here is my code below -

```
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.sql.Statement;
import java.util.HashMap;

public class Conn {
    public static String url        = "jdbc:mysql://127.9.77.2:3306/mysql";
    public static String user   = "adminSKr7Tbz";
    public static String password = "h1xha****";

    public static void main(String[] args) throws ClassNotFoundException, SQLException {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
        Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection(url,user,password);
        System.out.println("Connecting to database...");
        Statement stmt = conn.createStatement();
        ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery("select * from country LIMIT 10;");
        while (rs.next()) {
            HashMap map =  new HashMap();
            String name = rs.getString("Name");
            Integer col       = Integer.parseInt(rs.getString("Area"));
            map.put("name",name);
            map.put("value",col);
            System.out.println(map);

        }
    }
}
```

I get the following error -

```
Exception in thread "main" java.sql.SQLException: Access denied for user 'adminSKr7Tbz'@'localhost' (using password: YES)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:1056)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:957)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:3376)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:3308)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:894)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.secureAuth411(MysqlIO.java:3808)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.doHandshake(MysqlIO.java:1256)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.createNewIO(ConnectionImpl.java:2032)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.<init>(ConnectionImpl.java:729)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.JDBC4Connection.<init>(JDBC4Connection.java:46)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:526)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.handleNewInstance(Util.java:406)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.getInstance(ConnectionImpl.java:302)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.NonRegisteringDriver.connect(NonRegisteringDriver.java:283)
    at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:571)
    at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:215)
    at visualize.Conn.main(Conn.java:18)
```

Can anyone please help me fix this.
I am giving all credentials correctly , even then it says Access Denied.

Answer (score 0):

It is possible that MySQL is only setup to accept connections on local host. Can you update the grant statement to use 'user@%'

Answer (score 0):

```
String USERNAME = System.getEnv("OPENSHIFT_MYSQL_DB_USERNAME");
String PASSWORD = System.getEnv("OPENSHIFT_MYSQL_DB_PASSWORD");
String DB_NAME = System.getEnv("OPENSHIFT_APP_NAME");
String FORNAME_URL = "com.mysql.jdbc.Driver";
String URL = "jdbc:"+System.getEnv("OPENSHIFT_MYSQL_DB_URL")+ DB_NAME;
Connection m_connection = DriverManager.getConnection(URL , USERNAME , PASSWORD);
```

Use it like this.Openshift will not relay on static ip so they will not accept your connection via that ip or the localhost. Also if you are trying it on your local server rather that deploying it on openshift you have to use ssh tokens for the connection and i think it's not allowed.